# How to tell when a PHP Fatal Error is really a veiled Syntax Error, and when do they happen?

Tags: php, fatal-error, parse-error

**Considering the following PHP class:**

```
class someObject {
    public function broken(){
        return isset($this->something()) ? 'worked' : 'didnt';
    }

    public function something(){
        return true;
    }

    public function notBroken(){
        print('worked');
    }
}
```

**Let's say I now do:**

```
$obj= new someObject();
$obj->broken();
```

Considering you can't pass a function call to isset(), (it's by-reference), I expect this to fail with a fatal error: `PHP Fatal error:  Can't use method return value in write context` This is fine, and expected.

**However, let's say I now do:**

```
$obj= new someObject();
$obj->notBroken();
```

Considering I'm not hitting the `broken()` anywhere in this execution, and the error in `broken()` is a Fatal Error (and not a Parse error), I wouldn't expect the normal output of "worked". *FALSE! It still generates the Fatal Error.*

**Question:**

Aside from just not writing code that has errors, are there any other errors that are not Parse Errors but still trigger a runtime error? I only know about: `PHP Fatal error:  Can't use method return value in write context`. Is there any way to detect these errors?
Is there a special name for this type of error?

Comment: well it is not a parse error, it is perfectly valid syntax. That is also why it gives a fatal error, since it is not recoverable.
Also you can use php -l to check for these kind of errors in the code.
The parser will still give an error, and thus not runtime "Errors parsing broken_parser.php"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason for this specific behaviour is probably that `isset()` is a language construct and not a normal function that gets interpreted at runtime. So it stands to reason this is *kind of* a parse error.

I have no deep insight in this though, and I don't know whether this class of errors has a specific name.

Answer (score 0):

These are "compile errors", thrown by the compiler when it encounters a syntactically valid but "uncompilable"  construct. Go to http://svn.php.net/viewvc/php/php-src/trunk/Zend/zend_compile.c and search for "E_COMPILE_ERROR" - there are quite a few.